# Calculate driving time with OSM and Itinero

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openstreetmap

i want to write a program which is able to calculate the driving time from point A to point B with OSM and the library Itinero (http://www.itinero.tech/)

Currently i am doing the following:

1. Download the "pbf" Database from geofabrik.de
2. Convert the "pbf" into a routerdb file
3. Use the routerdb file in the code like in the following snippet:

   ```
   RouterDb routerDb = new RouterDb();

   string path = "PathToRouterDB";
   using (var stream = new FileInfo(path).OpenRead())
   {
       routerDb = RouterDb.Deserialize(stream);
   }

   router = new Router(routerDb);

   var profile = router.Db.GetSupportedProfile("car");

   Coordinate from = new Coordinate(fromLatidutde, fromLongitude);
   Coordinate to = new Coordinate(toLatitude, toLongitude);

   List<RouterPoint> points = new List<RouterPoint>
   {
       router.TryResolve(profile, from, 200),
       router.TryResolve(profile, to, 200)
   }

   var route = router.TryCalculate(profile, points.ToArray());

   float drivingTime = route.Value.TotalTime;
   ```

Is this the right way? When i'm calculating large distances (e.g 500km) it tooks 5 minutes to calculate the driving time, and this is too much for my program.

It would be great if someone has suggestions for me!

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: If Itinero's routing engine is too slow for large distances then consider switching to an external [OSM router](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) such as OSRM, GraphHopper or ValHalla.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You just have to add this: 
routerDb.AddContracted(profile);
On my PC it calculates similar distance for 3-4 seconds.

Comment: https://docs.itinero.tech/docs/itinero/tutorials/matrix-calculation.html